# Disabling microphones programmatically in Windows XP

Tags: c++, audio, windows-xp, microphone

I need to disable completely audio input devices(microphones) from a C++ code in Windows XP.

My purpose is to block the audio input devices so that no program can't capture the audio in XP.

First of all, is it possible?

If possible, please let me know how.

Comment: You may want to look at the Windows SetupAPI

Comment: Yes, I used SetupAPI to block audio devices. But I want to block the audio input devices only. Thanks for your answer.